# Avoid XML convertion in .apk to .apk.zip in android

Tags: android, obfuscation, decode, encode, android-xml

I create an application in android.
I know .apk can convert into .zip and my layout and xml files are extracted.
Is there any way to avoid the decoding of xml?
How can i encode the apk so it cannot converted?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

An .APK file is simply a .ZIP file with a predefined directory/file layout, there is no "conversion" (unless you're simply talking about changing the extension).

ProGuard can be used to obfuscate code, but there's no "standard" way of encoding/encrypting the XML files. You could encrypt/decrypt them manually yourself, but you'd be introducing a great amount of overhead at runtime for decryption, and many standard interfaces would not work because they expect the standard plan-text XML format. You're looking at a great deal of code to accomplish what you're asking. This is all assuming you're loking to encrypt your strings.xml, etc.

If you're looking to encrypt custom XML data files, there's a thread with some good suggestions [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c0b4697cd59dd880).